# Is there an equivalent command like this in SalesForce? EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to figure out how a Site table tie to Provisioning and other tables and I cannot find a single field that fits the bill.

In MSSQL, we can do an EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName' to get all foreign key reference to the given table.  Is there an equivalent command in SalesForce.

This is the first time I am working with SalesForce and I am trying to clean out some data, so if the question seems too trivial, pardon me please:)

Thanks!
Don

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce SOQL don't provide such wide opportunities, so for searching of any fields, like lookups for instance (it's the Salesforce equivalent of foreign keys in Relational databases like MSSQL) you need to use Salesforce UI and look for these fields manually (use browser page search). In case if you have sources of your Salesforce project locally you can use usual search by content (Salesforce objects metadata is usual XML).

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't say that.  Anyways, I have the data staged in a SQLServer database, and all I see that can be used to linked my 2 tables are 2 fields both have null values in them.  Is it possible for some records to be orphaned in SalesForce?  Thanks!